# I'm getting a error when I try to Sign up user

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm getting this error when I try to sign up user.
error: A value of type 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'. (invalid_assignment at [projectfooddelivery] lib\Src\models\user.dart:28). When I try to create the user in the firebase I cant do anything. I want to know how can I fix this error and how can I test if my app is properly connected to the firebase.

Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class UserModel extends Model{
    FirebaseAuth _auth=FirebaseAuth.instance;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    Map<String,dynamic> userData=Map();
    bool isLoading=false;



  void signIn()async{
 isLoading=true;
 notifyListeners();
 await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
 isLoading=false;
 notifyListeners();
  }
 void signUp({@required Map<String,dynamic>userData,@required String pass,@required VoidCallback onSuccess,@required VoidCallback onFail} ){
   isLoading=true;
   notifyListeners();
   _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
       email: userData["email"],
       password: pass
   ).then((user)async{
     firebaseUser=user;
     await _saveUserData(userData);
     onSuccess();
     isLoading=false;
     notifyListeners();
   }).catchError((e){
     onFail();
     isLoading=false;
     notifyListeners();
   });

 }
 void recoverPass(){

 }
 Future<Null> _saveUserData(Map<String,dynamic>userData)async{
   this.userData=userData;
   await Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).setData(userData);
 }
}
```

Comment: try after making signUp method async.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
   _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
       email: userData["email"],
       password: pass
   ).then((user)async{
     firebaseUser=user;
```

The method `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns `Future<AuthResult>` therefore `user` is of type `AuthResult`, and `firebaseUser` is of type `FirebaseUser`. You need to do the following:

```
   _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
       email: userData["email"],
       password: pass
   ).then((user)async{
     firebaseUser = user.user;
     print(firebaseUser.uid);
```

`AuthResult` contains the property [`user`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/auth_result.dart#L18) which returns the current user of type `FirebaseUser`

Comment: Thanks it worked. But I still cant get the registration to work can you guys take a look at the project.https://github.com/ValdoAmaral/fooddelivery2.git

Comment: Since the answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as correct so others know that it is helpful thank you!

Comment: Regarding cannot make registration work please ask it as a different question with code and explanation and don't share the whole repository..